# Are GPG Tools Keys Just Plains GnuPG Keys?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I generated a key pair with GPG Tools for Mac and exported the public and private key to a safe place.

I assume that I can decrypt my stuff with this USB in any OS (e.g. Linux) and any GnuPG software.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPG Tools is a distribution of GnuPG with some front end and integration addons. All key management and cryptographic operations is handled by GnuPG. You can also verify this by running `gpg --list-keys` on the command line, which will show the same keys the frontend tools know of.

Furthermore, GnuPG does implement the OpenPGP specification, so I'd rather call those keys "OpenPGP keys": they're also interoperable with other implementations of OpenPGP (PGP, OpenKeychain, the Monkeysphere development library, ...).

Comment: So I can encrypt messages with someones PGP Public Key and she can encrypt mine, right?

Comment: Yes, and no matter what implementation the other party is using, as long as it is OpenPGP compliant and supports the algorithms used.